# try catch no catching result

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I would like use try/catch for async function in my ES6 Class :

```
async loginThroughApi() {
  try {
    const request = await callServer(server.login_check);

    if (request.ok && request.status === 200) {
      Router.pushRoute('/');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('error');
  }
}
```

My request return an 401 code, i don't understand why i don't have the `catch` error ?

Anyone know if something is wrong ?

Comment: seems like `callServer ` does not throw in case of 4XX statuses, you should check it yourself:
`const request = await callServer(server.login_check);
if (request.status >= 400) throw new Error("failed") `

Comment: Why would you expect 401 to be caught as an exception when you are only testing for `request.status === 200` in your condition?